# Do we need NAT gateway/instance in public subnet when we want to distribute traffic from ELB to private subnet instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have configured lots of time, when my instance is in public subnet, I can distribute ELB traffic to them but instances in private subnet, it goes out of service. I had configure perfect SG between ELB to private instances and for ELB. Also added public subnet in ELB as same AZ where my private instances existing. I have done everything as per below URLs.

[Amazon ELB for EC2 instances in private subnet in VPC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22541895/amazon-elb-for-ec2-instances-in-private-subnet-in-vpc)

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/public-load-balancer-private-ec2/

As per first URLs, we don't require  NAT in public subnet if we don't require to access any other service from private instances, "havak5" and "been Whaley" also commented afor same,  still some websites tell that in this scenario, we need NAT gateway or instance in public subset for return traffic.
http://thebluenode.com/exposing-private-ec2-instances-behind-public-elastic-load-balancer-elb-aws

I had tried as per AWS URLs mention above but not work. So can any one  tell me that really how this scenario work?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the following link from aws to understand use of NAT:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html

If we want to make any kind of interaction with instances placed in private subnet we should use NAT